# Booting iMac in Recovery partition takes forever

Tags: macos, time-machine, imac, recovery

I'm trying to boot the recovery partition on my Mid 2010 iMac 27 to do a Time Machine recovery.

OSX is installed correctly already and I can boot that quickly. However, when I try to boot the recovery partition I get the grey screen with apple logo and a progress bar. This one is so slow I have the feeling there is no progress at all, while my machine sounds like it is doing a lot of stuff. What can this be? Is this normal?

Or is there also another way to recover my mac without recovery partition?

Comment: Do you have a SSD or Solid State Drive?

Comment: yes I have both an SSD and HDD. SSD contains OSX (and is `disk0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in the mean time I have:

- Updated OSX from 10.10 to 10.11
- Tried regular recovery again, and now it worked. Guessing the update fixed the recovery disk somehow.

Now in process of restoring the mac.